# How can I prove the following derivative

Tags: calculus

How can I prove that (fgh)'(x) = f'(x)g(x)h(x) + f'(x)g'(x)h(x) + f(x)g(x)h'(x)?

Comment: Do you know the product rule?

Answer (score 3):

$(fgh)'(x) = (f\cdot(gh))'(x)= f'(x)(gh(x)) + f(x)(gh)'(x)$ by the product rule. Using the product rule again for $(gh)'(x)$ gives the result.